# PHP Can't find save handler memcache

Tags: php, apache, memcached

I'm busting my brains over this issue (it should be straightforward), but can't seem to find a solution so hopefully one of you can help me.  I'm trying to store sessions using php's memcache extension.

I'm running MAMP and have installed the extension correctly (I think...it shows up when I do phpinfo), am running the daemon and can connect to it through php, using something like this:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

So I KNOW that php can communicate with the daemon. The problem is when I enable memcache session storage in php.ini and try to do a session_start() it gives me an error that it "Cannot find save handler memcache".  This is what is in my php.ini:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Any help would be much appreciated =(

Some additional info:

Installed using the directions here:

http://lullabot.com/articles/setup-memcached-mamp-sandbox-environment

on OSX 1.6.4 and i put the .so file in the proper directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Memcached, not Memcache. Same as the name of the class.

```
session.save_handler = memcached
```

**EDIT** since the OP indicated that it was just a typo.

There are some similar stories here:
http://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/
http://phpslacker.com/2009/03/02/php-session-clustering-with-memcache/

Did you say "yes" when the installer asked you "Enable memcache session handler support?"

If it doesn't work, try the new Memcached extension (with the D). It's supposed to be better somehow.

Comment: ah sorry I typoed my post, I am using the memcache.so extension, so when I use save_handler = memcached it throws the same error.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had to run the "pecl install memcache" command to build the extension and enable support.  works on my production boxes but unfortunately not for MAMP, I guess i have to figure out a way to recompile the extension for the version I have.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `memcached` instead of `memcache`, make sure you don't have `tcp://` in your `session.save_path`. So you should fix your `session.save_path` from

```
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211"
```

to

```
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Comment: There is NO telling just how much time your post saved me. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU.

Answer (score 5):

You might just still need to install the PHP memcached extension, for example `yum install php55-pecl-memcached`

Comment: Or try: apt-get install php-memcache php-memcached

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable the memcache session handler support then installing php5-memcache. Which OS are you using and how have you installed it?

Comment: I followed the instructions here http://www.lullabot.com/articles/setup-memcached-mamp-sandbox-environment, using OSX 1.6.4 and i put the .so file in the proper directory