# Warning : session_start(): Cannot find save handler 's' - session startup failed

Tags: php

I can't seem to start a session. Whenever I do I get the following: Warning
: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 's' - session startup failed in

Comment: I think that you have typo in `php.ini` in `session.save_handler`. Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057777/php-cant-find-save-handler-memcache). It may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the session save path in **php.ini**

```
session.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
```

Otherwise, you can use it in code as per your requirements:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/your/folder')
```