# Changing from mod_mpm_prefork to mod_mpm_event

Tags: php, apache, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to change my apache to start using threads.
So I changed from mod_mpm_prefork to mod_mpm_event.

After that, I started receiving this message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot find save handler 'memcached' in Unknown on line 0
```

The only file I changed was 00-mpm.conf, this is how it looks now.

```
# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines:

# prefork MPM: Implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

# worker MPM: Multi-Processing Module implementing a hybrid
# multi-threaded multi-process web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# event MPM: A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming
# threads only for connections with active processing
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
#
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

I already checked that I have memcached module.
Also, I didn't change anything but this, so I think configuration must be okay.

Comment: You might have gone through this already, but are you sure you are configured for memcached and not memcache? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057786/231316

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks chris! But yes, I already verified that